# OSX Entitlement For "system-socket" Responsible for CWInterface Notifications?

Tags: objective-c, sandbox, nsnotification, entitlements, corewlan

When I register for CoreWLAN notifications (with a retained interface) like this:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(recieveNetworkNotificationAndRedirectToMainThread:) 
                                             name:CWSSIDDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

I receive the notification only when I have all entitlements ***disabled***. None of the default entitlements allow me to receive this (or other CoreWLAN) notification.

Any ideas?

10.7.4

---

**Edit 1:**

The [Entitlements Reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/EnablingAppSandbox/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW1) did not provide any assistance.

---

**Edit 2:**

Faking the notification works fine:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 postNotificationName:CWSSIDDidChangeNotification 
 object:self];
```

And none of the [other CoreWLAN notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CoreWLANConstants_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) are received either.

I am sure that this is a simple entitlement that I'm missing... Here is the entitlement file with the temp exception for Growl (removing the temp exception has no effect either):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <string>com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
    <string>GrowlApplicationBridgePathway</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

**Edit 3:**

Compiling for 10.6 using the old k-prefixed notification names has no effect either.

---

**Edit 4:**

More information from the logs:

> AppName (39009) deny system-socket
>
> Process:         AppName [39009] Path:
>   /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-fnxrpqnodsouovcaxgiocvnfpqor/Build/Products/Release/AppName/Contents/MacOS/AppName
>   Load Address:    0x10d23f000 Identifier:      AppName Version:
>   ??? (???) Code Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent Process: 
>   debugserver [39007]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-07-20 13:17:11.851 -0700 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.4 (11E2705) Report Version:  7
>
> Backtrace: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff98704e76
>   socket + 10 1   CoreWLAN                          0x00007fff951f4a6f
>   Apple80211EventMonitoringInit2 + 53 2   CoreWLAN
>     0x00007fff951e6dc4 -[CWInterface initWithInterfaceName:] + 1358 3
>   CoreWLAN                          0x00007fff951e412d +[CWInterface
>   interfaceWithName:] + 52 4   CoreWLAN
>     0x00007fff951e41a8 +[CWInterface interface] + 98

---

**Edit 5:**

Found [this reference to deny system-socket in sandboxd](http://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Apple-Sandbox-Guide-v0.1.pdf), but no help yet.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help at all? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525858/nsnotification-troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525858/nsnotification-troubles)

Comment: No, that does not answer the question. I don't have issues with receiving the notification ... only when the app has entitlements enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get SSID changes and updates with my app sandboxed using the networknotifier code in hardwaregrowler - I think because its looking for specific notifications.

http://code.google.com/p/growl/source/browse/Extras/HardwareGrowler/?name=default

Once I am notified of a change:

```
if(wif==nil){
    wif = [CWInterface interface];
    [wif retain];
}
if(!wif.serviceActive){
    skip=TRUE;
}
if(wif.ssid==nil){
    skip=TRUE;
}
if(!skip)
if(wif){
    NSLog(@"We are on the WiFi network: %@",wif.ssid);
}
```

Comment: Well, this might work - but do you have any idea what's going on with the entitlements?

Comment: No progress on understanding the entitlements issue... any ideas?