# Is there a way to get a notification when my iOS device joins a wifi network?

Tags: ios

I'd like to do a simple location aware application that minimizes impact on battery life.  In my case, it would actually be quite sufficient just to know that I've joined a particular wifi network.

Does anyone know of a way to get a background notification whenever my device joins a wifi network?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790957/reachability-guide-for-ios-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use CoreWLAN framework to get info about that https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/_index.html

Comment: I just looked through that framework (admittedly, briefly) but did not see any sort of notification capability.

Comment: Check this out if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047338/is-there-a-nsnotificationcenter-notification-for-wifi-network-changes

Comment: It looks like this reference is what I'm looking for.  The reachabilty stuff seems more oriented to whether or not a particular endpoint is "reachable" (and if, so, by what means).  I want to be able to detect when my device has joined a specific network, and it appears that this article and answers will get me going in the right direction.  It's the System Configuration piece that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reachability to check you device is connected with wifi or not. Check the code [here](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html)

Comment: I looked at reachability, but did not see anything for notifications.  I suppose I could just periodically wake up and check, but, given that ios just joins the network when it sees it, I was hoping I could get a notification to wake my app only when that happened.

Comment: @MikeCargal it will call the method when wifi is detected or when its disconnected. Download the code from here check here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Reachability.zip and check it.

Answer (score 0):

(comment) Do you mean when your device automatically connects to a wifi network?

Comment: yes (preferably, just tell me when I connect to a network I identify, but I could easily settle for a notification on connection to any wifi network, as long as I can determine which network I just connected to.)